# Parsing Mbox from an open file-like object in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.7

This works:

```py
import mailbox

x = mailbox.mbox('filename.mbox')  # works
```

but what if I only have an open handle to the file, instead of a filename?

```py
fp = open('filename.mbox', mode='rb')  # for example; there are many ways to get a file-like object
x = mailbox.mbox(fp)  # doesn't work
```

**Question**: What's the best (cleanest, fastest) way to open Mbox from a bytes stream = an open binary handle, without copying the bytes into a named file first?

Answer (score 4):

`mailbox.mbox()` has to call the builtin function `open()` at some point. Thus a hacky solution would be to intercept that call and return the pre-existing file-like object. A draft solution follows:

```
import builtins

# FLO stands for file-like object

class MboxFromFLO:

    def __init__(self, flo):
        original_open = builtins.open

        fake_path = '/tmp/MboxFromFLO'
        self.fake_path = fake_path
        def open_proxy(*args):
            print('open_proxy{} was called:'.format(args))
            if args[0] == fake_path:
                print('Call to open() was intercepted')
                return flo
            else:
                print('Call to open() was let through')
                return original_open(*args)

        self.original_open = original_open
        builtins.open = open_proxy
        print('Instrumenting open()')

    def __enter__(self):
        return mailbox.mbox(self.fake_path)

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback):
        print('Restoring open()')
        builtins.open = self.original_open



# Demonstration
import mailbox

# Create an mbox file so that we can use it later
b = mailbox.mbox('test.mbox')
key = b.add('This is a MboxFromFLO test message')

f = open('test.mbox', 'rb')
with MboxFromFLO(f) as b:
    print('Msg#{}:'.format(key), b.get(key))
```

Some caveats with regard to possible future changes in the implementation of `mailbox.mbox`:

1. `mailbox.mbox` may also open extra files besides the one passed to its constructor. Even if it doesn't, the monkey-patched `open()` will be used by any other Python code executed while the patch is in effect (i.e. as long as the context managed by `MboxFromFLO` is active). You must ensure that the fake path you generate (so that you can later recognize the correct call to `open()` if there are more than one such calls) doesn't conflict with any such files.
2. `mailbox.mbox` may decide to somehow check the specified path before opening it (e.g. using `os.path.exists()`, `os.path.isfile()`, etc) and will fail if that path doesn't exist.

Comment: Interesting approach. How "hacky" is this hacky solution? What other properties does `Mailbox` rely on, apart from `open`, that I would need to monkey-patch too?

Answer (score 1):

You could subclass mailbox.mbox. [The source code for the standard library can be found on github.](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/mailbox.py)

The logic seems to be mostly implemented in the superclass `_singlefileMailbox`.

```
class _singlefileMailbox(Mailbox):
    """A single-file mailbox."""

    def __init__(self, path, factory=None, create=True):
        """Initialize a single-file mailbox."""
        Mailbox.__init__(self, path, factory, create)
        try:
            f = open(self._path, 'rb+')
        except OSError as e:
            if e.errno == errno.ENOENT:
                if create:
                    f = open(self._path, 'wb+')
                else:
                    raise NoSuchMailboxError(self._path)
            elif e.errno in (errno.EACCES, errno.EROFS):
                f = open(self._path, 'rb')
            else:
                raise
        self._file = f
        self._toc = None
        self._next_key = 0
        self._pending = False       # No changes require rewriting the file.
        self._pending_sync = False  # No need to sync the file
        self._locked = False
        self._file_length = None    # Used to record mailbox size
```

So we can try to get rid of the open() logic, and also replace the init code from mbox and the other superclasses.

```
class CustomMbox(mailbox.mbox):
    """A custom mbox mailbox from a file like object."""

    def __init__(self, fp, factory=None, create=True):
        """Initialize mbox mailbox from a file-like object."""

        # from `mailbox.mbox`
        self._message_factory = mailbox.mboxMessage

        # from `mailbox._singlefileMailbox`
        self._file = fp
        self._toc = None
        self._next_key = 0
        self._pending = False       # No changes require rewriting the file.
        self._pending_sync = False  # No need to sync the file
        self._locked = False
        self._file_length = None    # Used to record mailbox size

        # from `mailbox.Mailbox`
        self._factory = factory

    @property
    def _path(self):
        # If we try to use some functionality that relies on knowing 
        # the original path, raise an error.
        raise NotImplementedError('This class does not have a file path')

    def flush(self):
       """Write any pending changes to disk."""
       # _singlefileMailbox has quite complicated flush method.
       # Hopefully this will work fine.
       self._file.flush()
```

This could be a start. But you would probably have to define additional methods to get the full functionality of the other mailbox classes.